# Grab the data exceed one more day

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select CASE 
WHEN (shipment_date >=((to_char(shipment_date, 'dd-Mon-yyyy 08:00')::timestamp)) and shipment_date < ((to_char(shipment_date, 'dd-Mon-yyyy 20:00')::timestamp )))
THEN to_char(shipment_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy 08:00') 
WHEN (shipment_date >=((to_char(shipment_date, 'dd-Mon-yyyy 20:00')::timestamp)) and shipment_date < ((to_char(shipment_date + interval '1' day, 'dd-Mon-yyyy 08:00')::timestamp )))
THEN to_char(shipment_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy 20:00')
END as shipment_date_sort,
COUNT(lotnumber) 
from shipping.picklist_lots 
inner join shipping.picklist on picklist_lots.picklist_id = picklist.picklist_id 
where shipment_date >= '12/23/2014' and shipment_date < '12/24/2014'
GROUP BY shipment_date_sort
```

it doesnt give me the result which the shipment date between 24/12/2014 00:00 and 24/12/2014 08:00

i need it

Comment: Can you share which DBMS you're using? It looks like Oracle to me, but Oracle isn't going to recognize '12/23/2014', for example, as a date without the `TO_DATE()` function.

Comment: postgresql, pg admin

Comment: the thing i want to mention is... i unable to pull out the data between 24/12/2014 00:00 to 24/12/2014 08:00

Comment: are you certain that these data actually exist in your table?

Comment: of course, i tried to use another select statement to ensure if my data pulling is correct, but the result was dissapointing me

Answer (score 0):

```
where shipment_date >= '12/23/2014' and shipment_date < '12/24/2014'
```

Add a time value. According to your datetime value, 24/12/2014 00:00, it should be in format (dd/MM/yyyy 00:00)

```
where shipment_date >= '23/12/2014' and shipment_date <= '24/12/2014 23:59'
```

Comment: Hi, the main purpose i putting this is because i want to grab the data of one day only, start from 23/12/2014 00:00 to 24/12/2014

Comment: the problem i want to solve is, i want to grab the data between 8am to 8pm as morning shift, the 8pm to "another day" as night shift, thats why i need to cross day to do the grouping

Comment: Since you are not specifying a time in your WHERE clause, it defaults to 00:00, which would not include records between 24/12/2014 00:00 and 24/12/2014 08:00. But knowing which DBMS you are using would be helpful as David Faber said.

Comment: Hi i know what u mean, and i tried, still doesnt work, it direct clear out the data between 00:00 and 08:00

Answer (score 0):

Based on logical query processing, you cannot use alias of your `SELECT` statement in group by because `SELECT` happens after `GROUP BY` so you need to duplicate your `CASE` statement into your `GROUP BY` part.

[LOGICAL QUERY PROCESSING](http://www.sqlabout.com/logical-query-processing/)

Comment: I tried, the data still same output , unable to grab the data between 24/12/2014 00:00 and 24/12/2014 08:00